# Keyboard Shortcut for "Export Unmodified Original For 1 Photo..."

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I'd like to make a keyboard shortcut to export unmodified originals in Photos.

The menu entry changes and shows the number of photos that are selected (sometimes it also says items).

So if I create a shortcut (in System Preferences, Keyboard, then Shortcuts) that says `Export Unmodified Original For 1 Photo...` it works for one photo but not for two.

Can I create a shortcut that works regardless of the number of photos selected?